# What is the term for when one letter is lowercased when a name is in all caps?

Tags: capitalization, typography

Oftentimes when my last name is used in all caps on official documents, one of the letters is lowercased to denote that the following letter is capitalized. For example:

DeVos = DeVOS

What is the term for this? I've reviewed other questions regarding camel case and Pascal case, but I haven't been able to find an answer. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: I think your assumption about the capitalisation is incorrect; the French form of the name would have been *de Vos* where only the V of *Vos* was capitalised, since that is the proper noun. Officials and computers find such things hard to deal with, so they capitalise the D as well, reasoning that that must be the first letter of the name.  But your question remains a good one: *MacDuff* has always been one word, and some branches use a capital D though some a small one.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. My last name exists with two capital letters. Granted, when my ancestors came to North America, their proper last name was preceded  by "de", but they chose to alter the name to differentiate themselves.

Comment: So what is the question here? The one in the title is completely different from the one in the body.

Comment: Several names in that format morph in that way. We can find the permutations du Bois/Du Bois/DuBois/Dubois on the [Wikipedia disambiguation page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Du_Bois), much like with de Vos/De Vos/DeVos. I've always thought the second-letter-in-lower-case-in-an-otherwise ALL CAPS format was meant to indicate the third letter goes in upper case in the "normal" format, so (DeVOS ⇒ DeVos) but (DEVOS ⇒ Devos). Moreover, (DelGRECO ⇒ Del Greco) and (DELGRECO ⇒ Delgreco), but I'm no expert in the matter, and I couldn't find much guidance on that convention, much less a name for it.

Comment: De Vos is Dutch, not French. It means "the fox". Therefore the D should be capitalised. Nevertheless, some pretentious Dutch speakers may use a lower case to make it appear as French "de" i.e. "of" used in the surnames of nobility. Equally French speakers who have ended up with a Dutch surname (common in Belgium) may use a lowercase D.

Comment: As aother example "Mc" names (from Scotland and the Scotch-Irish) were occassionaly written McNAME when "all" caps was called for. No idea if the convention has a descriptive word.

Comment: Since we are on this subject, it may help to know that the prepositions inserted between first and last name are called [*tussenvoegsels*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tussenvoegsel) in Dutch. I don't know if similar words exist in any other languages.

Comment: Related: [Should a name that is capitalized contain a lower case letter, for example, McDONALD or MCDONALD?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/119570)

Answer (score 1):

"Mixed case" might be precise enough.

Answer (score 0):

For a brief history of all caps, see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_caps#Usage). Now: there is likely not a term for your case, as it is a very specific rule applying to a very limited application. I'd recommend creating a concise description, or even coming up with your own term. "Delineating lowercase" or "Delineated Caps" spring readily to mind.