# Should a name that is capitalized contain a lower case letter, for example, McDONALD or MCDONALD?

Tags: writing-style, capitalization

If the name is capitalized, for example, should it be McDONALD or MCDONALD?

Comment: *McDonald* is already capitalized.  You’re talking about something else.

Comment: Using a lowercase letter in a capitalized name is illegal in seventeen states already.

Comment: -1 Surnames aren't usually capitalised, so the answer to this question is probably going to depend on why it is capitalised in the first place.

Comment: @toryan NB: “Capitalized” means that the first letter is in uppercase.  It is not the same as writing something in all capitals.

Comment: @tchrist Fair enough, although I meant all caps in the same way as the question.

Comment: Clearly, this is for METARs or NOTAMs coming from McDonald Observatory ...

Answer (score 11):

This is a matter of personal preference and/or a style guide, but here's what I recall from one usage authority (*The Right Word at the Right Time*, published by the Reader's Digest).

> Smith > SMITH
>   La Salle > LA SALLE
>   LaSalle > LaSALLE
>   la Salle > LA SALLE
>   Macdonald > MACDONALD
>   MacDonald > MacDONALD
>   McDonald > McDONALD